# Change suggestion choice shortcuts Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

In Visual Studio Code I can change the keyboard shortcuts for navigating the suggestion window easily.

[image]

Can I do the same in Intellij IDEA? I havent' been able to find a way so far.

Comment: Did you try the [Up/Down actions](https://i.imgur.com/c2NIJXi.png)?

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA you can [customize the keyboard shortcuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZRJX.png) for the Up and Down actions in the Keymap Settings.